# Save commands used in shell to a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, terminal

Someone is going to connect to my server and type some commands into the terminal. But after finishing his work, he deletes `bash_history`.

I am looking for a way to save every command entered into the terminal in a file so that if `bash_history` is deleted, these commands will be saved in another file automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is to enable `auditd` with a rule like `-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F euid=0 -S execve` in place. This will not catch everything but it is close. You will also have to monitor the audit log files closely as they will grow very quickly.

You might be able to come close by setting `HISTFILE` to record to a directory that is write-only. The user can re-define `HISTFILE` if he is aware of what is happening. You will need to investigate setting ACL's on a directory to make it read-only. It is possible and I've done it but I am not going to try to re-create the `setfacl` necessary for it.

Final answer is that if you don't trust the user they should now have access to your server. They definitely shouldn't have privileged access without a lot of trust involved.